# Windows Media Foundation - Using Analog Camera's / Capture Cards

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I was wondering if WMF will support analog cameras ? I'm currently using a Osprey 440 capture card, it does not come with a UVC 1.1 driver.

Is there anyway to use with capture card with windows media foundation for video capture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short anwser is no, not out of the box atm.